# How do I add validation to an embedded schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How do I add validation to this schema such that at least 1 property of account needs to be provided. It can be any 1 of the 4?

```js
interface IPlan {
  accounts: {
    facebook?: string;
    instagram?: string;
    linkedin?: string;
    x?: string;
  };
}

const PlanSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IPlan>(
  {
    accounts: {
      facebook: {
        type: String,
      },
      instagram: {
        type: String,
      },
      linkedin: {
        type: String,
      },
      x: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model<IPlan>('Plan', PlanSchema);
```